Mutual Funds Statement for Netherlands Schengen Visa Application
I'm applying for a Schengen visitor visa for the Netherlands from India. I'll be visiting my sister, and I'll be paying for all the expenses.
Over the last 2 years, I invested about 80% of my salary into mutual funds (through Coin from Zerodha). For this reason, my bank account balance is very low compared to my Mutual Funds balance.
I read a few answers, and all of them suggest that we can also use our MF balance in the application. But, which document should I specifically show for the MF investments? Should it be stamped/attested by the company (in my case Zerodha)? While banks are known to stamp the documents, do companies like Zerodha offer such services? I've never even been to their office.
Should I show the CDSL Consolidated Account Statement? I don't see any other document from Zerodha which shows the list of my holdings.
Thanks in advance and I truly appreciate your help.

Surely the key point of providing financial evidence is to show you have sufficient disposable resources to pay for the trip? Do you have that without the MF funds? Are the latter liquid/readily available to you? For the NL you need proof that you have at least €55 to spend per day for the whole duration of your stay in the country, excluding travel costs etc

@Traveller I suppose Vishnu could include a statement that if they get the visa they would transfer funds from the investments.

@Traveller, yes, I have sufficient disposable resources for the trip in my account. This can be seen from my bank statement.

I was curious about including MF since I read online that we need to show we have a reason to return back to India. I don't have any properties in my name (all in parents name).

@Vishnu Unless you can only access MF from India, they are not a compelling reason to return home. A good travel history, a family and a job that require your presence in India are typically what applicants need to demonstrate.

@Traveller Oh okay, got it thanks. How do I show I have family in India?

@Vishnu Marriage certificate, proof of support provided to dependent relatives that requires your presence in India (ie not just financial support). See also the graphic in Schengen visa refused “intention to leave could not be ascertained and Helpful tips for preparing a Schengen visa application

Honestly all these things don’t matter they will care about one thing if you are not a potential immigrant and how they determine that no one knows , but you could definitely show your investments, the impetus would be on the amount of money in your bank account. VO rarely checks and cares about your investment , you could easily forge that document and show 200 millions and specifically you are visiting a relative so you have to be extra cautious in this case. So in nutshell provide more documents of why you will come back added to other required documents

@SaranshSharma impetus?

Sorry importance instead of impetus
